# PyTables dtype alignment issue

Tags: python, numpy, memory-alignment, pytables

Consider the following code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tables as tb

# Pass the field-names and their respective datatypes as
# a description to the table
dt = np.dtype([('doc_id', 'u4'), ('word', 'u4'), 
    ('tfidf', 'f4')], align=True)

# Open a h5 file and create a table
f = tb.openFile('corpus.h5', 'w')
t = f.createTable(f.root, 'table', dt, 'train set',
    filters=tb.Filters(5, 'blosc'))

r = t.row
for i in xrange(20):
    r['doc_id'] = i
    r['word'] = np.random.randint(1000000)
    r['tfidf'] = rand()
    r.append()
t.flush()

# structured array from table
sa = t[:]

f.close()
os.remove('corpus.h5')
```

I have passed in an aligned `dtype` object, but when I observe `sa`, I get the following:

```
print dt
print "aligned?", dt.isalignedstruct
print
print sa.dtype
print "aligned?", sa.dtype.isalignedstruct

>>> 

    {'names':['doc_id','word','tfidf'], 'formats':['<u4','<u4','<f4'], 'offsets':[0,4,8], 'itemsize':12, 'aligned':True}
    aligned? True

    [('doc_id', '<u4'), ('word', '<u4'), ('tfidf', '<f4')]
    aligned? False
```

The structured array is not aligned. Is there no current way to enforce alignment in PyTables, or what am I doing wrong?

Edit: I've noticed my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999229/pytables-table-dtype-alignment?rq=1), but I've copied and tried its provided answer, but it doesn't work either.

---

Edit2: (See Joel Vroom's answer below)

I've replicated Joel's answer and tested to see if it is truly unpacked through Cython. Turns out it is:

```
In [1]: %load_ext cythonmagic

In [2]: %%cython -f -c=-O3
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: cimport numpy as np
   ...: import tables as tb
   ...: f = tb.openFile("corpus.h5", "r")
   ...: t = f.root.table
   ...: cdef struct Word: # notice how this is not packed
   ...:     np.uint32_t doc_id, word
   ...:     np.float32_t tfidf
   ...: def main(): # <-- np arrays in Cython have to be locally declared, so put array in a function
   ...:     cdef np.ndarray[Word] sa = t[:3]
   ...:     print sa
   ...:     print "aligned?", sa.dtype.isalignedstruct
   ...: main()
   ...: f.close()
   ...: 
[(0L, 232880L, 0.2658001184463501) (1L, 605285L, 0.9921777248382568) (2L, 86609L, 0.5266860723495483)]
aligned? False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to align data in PyTables :(
In practice I have done one of two things to get around this:

1. I perform one extra step --> `np.require(sa, dtype=dt, requirements='ACO')` **or**
2. I arrange the fields in my dtype description such that they are aligned.

As an example for the 2nd option, suppose I have the following dtype:
`dt = np.dtype([('f1', np.bool),('f2', '<i4'),('f3', '<f8')], align=True)`
If you print `dt.descr` you will see that a void space has been added to align the data:
`dt.descr >>> [('f1', '|b1'), ('', '|V3'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f8')]`
But, if I ordered my dtype like this (largest to smallest bytes):
`dt = np.dtype([('f3', '<f8'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f1', np.bool)])`
The data is now aligned regardless of whether I specify `align = True/False`.

Someone please correct me if I am wrong but even though `dt.isalignedstruct = False` if it has been ordered as shown above it is technically aligned. This has worked for me in applications where I need to send aligned data to C.

In the example you provided, even though `sa.dtype.isalignedstruct = False` given that
`dt.descr = [('doc_id', '<u4'), ('word', '<u4'), ('tfidf', '<f4')]` **and**
`sa.dtype.descr = [('doc_id', '<u4'), ('word', '<u4'), ('tfidf', '<f4')]`
The `sa` array is aligned (no void spaces added to the descr).

Comment: Option #1 is not always feasible given that your data needs to be loaded into memory to perform the alignment.

Comment: I have updated my question to show that it is indeed technically aligned